# Why doesn't this break terminate the program, but instead proceeds to the next operation?

Tags: c++, while-loop, break

How to exit the program with this code when I don't write the correct password after 3 trials?

The `break` is not terminating the program, but instead it goes to the next code block.

```
    int cod = 2334;
    while (true){
      cout << "Introduce your password." << endl;
      cin >> cod;       
       while(pass!=cod){
         int counter =1;
         cout << "Wrong password. You have three trials" << endl;
         cin >> cod;                    
         counter++;
         if (counter == 4)
            break;
    }
```

Comment: counter will never hit 4.

Answer (score 3):

`break` exit the inner most block. You have 2 `while` so it will only escape the inner one. Also your counter will never reach 4 because you keep resetting it to 1 with each loop. Try this instead:

```
int cod = 2334;
int counter = 1;

cout << "Introduce your password." << endl;
cin >> cod;       
while(pass!=cod && counter < 4){    
    cout << "Wrong password. You have three trials" << endl;
    cin >> cod;                    
    counter++;
}
```